# Change the color of all the td inside a table class in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to select all the bottom borders inside a table, and turn them gray, without having to assign a class to each td. So far what I have come up with is this, but it does not work:

```
table.items {
    border: 1px solid #42536f;
}

table.items > td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

Basically, I want to be able to just use the "items" class for the entire table, and have all the bottom borders show up gray, and the outside border show up that dark blueish color I chose.

Any suggestions?

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`td` is not the direct child of the `table`

```
table.items{ 
    border:1px solid #42536f;
}
table.items td{ 
    border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;
}
```

Here all td elements inside the table will select.

or

```
table.items{
    border:1px solid #42536f;
}
table.items>tr>td{
    border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;
}
```

In this case `td` is direct child of `tr` and `tr` is direct child of `table`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried 

table.items td{ 
    border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;
}

and it worked perfectly!

Comment: @balki use `table.items td,table.items th {`

Answer (score 2):

`table.items td` or `table.items > tr > td` will do the required job as suggested by others already.

But, may be.. giving `border-bottom` to rows instead of cells.. i.e, giving it to `table.items > tr` will give a better look. I am not sure if that is what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

With `table.items > td` you say:

> Every *td* that is a **direct** child of *table.items*

which is never given, because there's always a `<tr>` between.

Try using `table.items td` (like Pranav Ram suggested)!